# Using a PS-specific package with XeTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, postscript

I've a package I'd much like to use, MayaPS (for typesetting Mayan glyphs, with many features that make glyph composition easy), but the package comes only as a PostScript thing, and the authors have no intent of porting it for pdftex, xetex or the like. The standard process I seem to've cobbled together thus far is to just use pure latex to compile the individual blocks via LaTeX to dvi>ps>pdf and then include them one by one as PDF graphics, but surely there must be a better way.

The package itself is available for download from http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~orevkov/mayaps.html and the tarball has an example file included.

A (near-)minimal working example, cobbled together from the documentation source, would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input epsf
\def\mayaNoPreloadedFont{}
\input mayaps
\mayaFont\codex=codex-d
\codex
\mayaFont\typeone=T1example
\mayaFont\thtwo=thompson2

\begin{document}
\mayaRGB{0 0 0.8}c \mayaRGB{0.9 0.6 0}{orange}
{\mayaUndefine{314/314}
\maya{451.452orange  026.(314/314)c  (570/014`r.267.024)c}.
}
{\mayaSize{20pt}
$\quad L=$\maya{504.001} 
$\quad U=$\maya{504:001} 
$\quad R=$\maya{001.504} 
$\quad D=$\maya{001:504} 
$\quad S=$\hskip-8pt\maya{504}
}

\end{document}
```

The document it produces is looks like:

[image: Compilation Result]

The programs invoked, in order, were latex>dvips>ps2pdf, on a MikTeX distribution.

Comment: is the package available, can you post an example document?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it's available (just edited the question with a link) and the example document provided with the package is too large to post but can be found in the download.

Comment: I have doubts that one could fully move this to xetex. But perhaps one could at least automate the creation of the graphics e.g. with the tikzexternalize library or auto-ps-pdf. Do you have an example of a simple document that creates one of your graphics?

Comment: the cotrace program, if you use it without `-c` will make eps files rather than fragments of a font, so you could modify the makefont script to make eps of each, and to use eps2pdf to get pdf from there, but there is still a lot of raw postscript in the tex support. It may work to try to convert the existing dvips usage to work via pstricks rather than raw `\special` and then see if the pstricks support in xetex/xdvipdfmx is enough to cover this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have included it in the question, and specified the exact path I took. I'm not sure how to automate any of this, or how to use pstricks as a replacement, as I'm not proficient enough, and I don't see a decent way of doing this short of rewriting the entire package on its own.

Comment: Perhaps a more salient question is what other things do you use that absolutely require `pdflatex` or `xelatex`?  Can't you just use `latex+dvips` for the whole document, without converting individual glyphs as images? Obviously `xelatex` gives you a broader range of fonts, and this is a clear advantage, but if that's the only reason, perhaps it's a compromise worth making.

Comment: It is a practice I considered, but I am in decent need of typographic support offered by some fonts (specifically Junicode and Brill), which makes workarounds using generic LaTeX & dvips unmanageable

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, since there is no good equivalent of Junicode as a Type1 font, that's for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not perfect, but could at least reduce the work a bit.

Create a stand alone document called mayaglyphs.tex, add the glyphs you want to use (at best in the correct size) and give them sensible labels:

```
\documentclass[multi]{standalone}

 \input epsf
 \def\mayaNoPreloadedFont{}
 \input mayaps
 \mayaFont\codex=codex-d
 \codex
 \mayaFont\typeone=T1example
 \mayaFont\thtwo=thompson2

\standaloneenv{mayaglyph}

\begin{document}


\begin{mayaglyph}\label{A}
\mayaRGB{0 0 0.8}c \mayaRGB{0.9 0.6 0}{orange}
{\mayaUndefine{314/314}
\maya{451.452orange  026.(314/314)c  (570/014`r.267.024)c}.
}
\end{mayaglyph}

\begin{mayaglyph}\label{B}
\maya{504.001}
\end{mayaglyph}

\begin{mayaglyph}\label{C}
\maya{001.504}
\end{mayaglyph}

\end{document}
```

Compile it with latex, dvips, pspdf. Move the `pdf` **and** the `aux`-file to the folder of your main document.

In your main document you can then do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xr,refcount}
\externaldocument[ma-]{mayaglyphs}
\newcommand\mayaglyph[1]{\includegraphics[page=\getpagerefnumber{ma-#1}]{mayaglyphs}}
\begin{document}
blblb \mayaglyph{A}
blbl  \mayaglyph{B}
blblb \mayaglyph{C}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the workflow I seem to be forced into, if I want to avoid severely tampering with many of the package's contents. A properly comprehensive answer, with the best possible ratio of convenience to usability, I think.